# Map different URL to a webapplication

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere, web-deployment, redirect

I have a web application deployed in IBM websphere .it has url www.abcgulf.com

Now we want two url point to the same application
www.abcgulf.com
www.abcuk.com

and whenever user access application through www.abcgulf.com we should be able to identify in code through some JVM properties or other configuration that this is coming from GULF and when user www.abcuk.com then it is coming from uk .

I tried the solution by checking url in code whether url contains gulf or UK based on that we set location gulf/UK but we want to make it configurable . does not want this checking in code .

Please help me with some solution.
Additionally we are thinking to add a http server in front of application server and send some property from there in application server so that we can identify from where request is coming. i am not sure how to do this  .
please suggest some way for this.if any additional info is required please comment.

Application Configuration-web application ,JAVA , Frontend-JSF,SOAP Client, BAckend-SOAP webservice

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to have web server in front of application server. There are many advantages of web server like More control over security, content with flexibility which provides optimum performance and high-level security in secure infrastructure.

Setup a web server where you can have two sites as your requirement suggests and set some request headers upon receiving.

Apart from dealing with this specific issue, you will have more control on incoming requests where you may want to have some security restrictions.